# how to use switch case like (if)?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I want to use switch like if in my code but I dont know how to use && in case !
this is my code

```
string a;
a = System.Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);

if (a.Contains('h') && a.Contains('s'))
{
    this.BackColor=Color.Red;
}
else if (a.Contains('r') && a.Contains('z')) 
{
    this.BackColor=Color.Black;

}

else if (a.Contains('a') && a.Contains('b'))
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Pink;

}
```

Comment: By the way, `textBox1.Text` is already a string. Don't bother calling `Convert.ToString()` on it. There's no need.

Comment: Psst, @ed, You can do it with pattern matching in c# 7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching

Comment: I must be confused -- I don't know how pattern matching allows what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Sajad, what you've got is reasonably clean, readable code. I don't see any need to change it.

Comment: @Will Oh crap. I just saw the `when`. I thought pattern matching was purely the whole type check they added to `switch`. Didn't even know you could add when expressions after all these months!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use the later versions of C# you can write it like this:

```
switch (st)
{
     case var s when s.Contains("asd") && s.Contains("efg"):
         Console.WriteLine(s);
         break;
     case var s when s.Contains("xyz"):
         break;
     // etc.
}
```

In your particular situation there is no need to introduce new local variables (`s`) so the code could be written as

```
switch(st)
{
     case var _ when st.Contains("asd") && st.Contains("efg"):
         Console.WriteLine(st);
         break;
     case var _ when st.Contains("xyz"):
         break;
     // etc.
}
```

You can read about it on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

Comment: +1 because whoa, cool -- but I think this isn't a better argument in favor of pattern matching in C# than Duff's Device is in favor of case fall-through in C.

Comment: You can avoid the creation of a new variable by using `var _`

Comment: Yeah, variables named `_` are always a good confusion sink.&lt;/grandpa simpson&gt;

Comment: As awesome as this is and does what the OP wants. I still prefer the `if` statements  xD

Comment: Actually, when a lot of "when" clauses are added to switch it quickly starts looking even worse than "if-else" chaining. I'll update the answer with "_" syntax in a second (it seems like it's relevant to this particular question)